# Retries on plink batch file error

Tags: batch-file, plink

Sometimes when sending that batch

```
plink 192.168.X.Y -l Admin -pw password -m C:\vsreset.txt
```

where vsreset.txt is

```
POWER reset
```

I receive some error like

```
FATAL ERROR .....
```

I would like to make a batch that retries until "no error found"
How can I do this?

I've tried something like this

```
c:\reset.bat | FIND "ERROR" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 resetplus.bat
```

but I alwais receive errorlevel = 1 and the routines doesn't stop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` returns `1` when it does **not** find the search string, so you need something like this instead:

```
@echo off
:repeat
plink 192.168.x.x ... | find "ERROR" >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto repeat
```

or shorter:

```
@echo off
:repeat
plink 192.168.x.x ... | find "ERROR" >nul && goto repeat
```